# Sitecore Scheduled Publish Module - India timezone utc +05:30

Tags: publishing, module

I'm using the Sitecore Scheduled Publish with the Timezone package from https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Scheduled_Publish.aspx
developed by Hedgehog.

This allow me to add some timezone, but is it possible to add the India timezone utc +05:30? I get a error in the scheduled publish dialog when I use +5:30 or +5.5 seem like it is only working for whole hours?

> Exception: System.FormatException Message: Input string was not in a
>   correct format. Source: mscorlib at
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at
>   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info) at
>   ScheduledPublish.Models.TimeZone.get_Offset() at
>   ScheduledPublish.sitecore.shell.Applications.Content_Manager.Dialogs.Schedule_Publish.SchedulePublishDialog.PublishDateTimePickerOnChanged(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArgs) at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DateTimePicker.OnChanged() at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DatePicker.DoChanged() at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DatePicker.HandleMessage(Message message)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.DispatchMessage(Control
>   control) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.Execute(CommandContext
>   context) at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.SendMessage(Message
>   message) at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DateCalendar.OnSelect() at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DateCalendar.DoClick(Message message)

Comment: What is the error? You have a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. (without changing the code)

In the Model (`ScheduledPublish.Models.Offset`) there is an `int.Parse`. so the value needs to be an integer.

Looks like the source is also not on GitHub. 
Although there is a feature-timezones branch https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/SCScheduledPublishing/tree/feature-timezones it seems like it is not about this timezone feature.

Also on GitHub is a newer version of the module version 1.1 instead of the 1.0 on the marketplace. but the timezone feature from this issue is not in there.

What you can do is de-compile the code, and change the model to

```
public double Offset
{
    get
    {
        return double.Parse(this.InnerItem[ID.Parse("{32BF3544-E4F1-4A09-80ED-CC654BD6A764}")]);
    }
}
```

This works, (the module is under the Apache License) the code to display is

```
universalTime.AddHours((double) timeZone.Offset).ToShortTimeString())
```

For UTC+5:30 you can now use

> 5.5